# my iPhone 6, 16gb is almost full because of the "other" space, how can I get rid of it?

Tags: itunes, iphone, space

Around 5gb is what my other space is taking up on my iPhone 6. I see this in iTunes when I hook my phone up to the computer. So I can't install more apps and I want to. How can I mend this, how can I delete this other space. I am sure I am not actively using 5gb of space. Most of the photos I uplpoad to facebook, and I doubt my saved games take up so much space. Which program can I use or something like that?

Answer (score 1):

First of all, you should know exactly what is the "Other". Because there are just too many things that require physical storage in iPhone. That's why Apple chose to lump a lot of things into the "Other" category. If there is many "other" storage on your iPhone 6, it's seems like your phone is filled with cached files and data. That can include:

- Documents & Data
- Safari browsing data
- Mail data
- iTunes data, including files that have been streamed (which can be BIG).

Deleting data, and then restoring is a good way, but you should back up first. or it will cause data lost. So it will take a little risk. Have you updated the application on your iPhone or upgraded iOS system to the newest version available? Some similar problems have been resolved using this way. If above ways still not work, you can choose some professional tools. You can try iMyfone Umate. It claims that this tool can optimize storage space and reduce the storage space occupied by apps to free up iPhone space. Maybe it's useful.

Answer (score 0):

Try using battery pro app, see if that will help clearing up your space. Should do the work at least somewhat.

Comment: Thanks I already tried it, but didn't get me much, maybe couple of megabytes, which is not really much.